# Should I create new component or render js conditionaly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, jsx

I have a case where I need to render one react component again in a different place. So, for example, I have an index component where I have a list of users and filters for this list. Now I need to render this component in a different place but without filters. Should I create a new almost the same index component and skip rendering filters or should I pass prop and render conditional JSX?

```js
const Index = ({ renderFilters }) => {
  ... some code
  return (
    <>
      ...some jsx code
      { renderFilters ? <Filters /> : null }
      <UserList>
      ...some jsx code
    </>
  )
}
```

or just copy-paste the index component and

```js
const IndexWithouFilters = () => {
  ... some code
  return (
    <>
      ...some jsx code
      <UserList>
      ...some jsx code
    </>
  )
}
```

Of course, this is only an example and I have a case where have to render conditionally more than one components.

Comment: The better option would be the conditional rendering

Comment: You should always look for ways to ensure you follow DRY (don't repeat yourself) as much as possible. Therefore, passing props that render conditionally would almost always be the correct answer to your question.

Answer (score 2):

It is a best practice in Reactjs to reuse components.So go with former approach.